# Moving files and folder from one server to another server using sftp or rsync

Tags: sftp, web-hosting, rsync

I bought another server from another web hosting and would like to transfer all files from my current host. I don't use cPanel on the new server so I would like to use either sftp or rsync.

My question is whether I should zip/tar all the files from my current host before transfering it to the new server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
    rsync -r -avH --exclude "exlude/dir" user@hostname:/from/source/* /to/destination >
    rsync_log_date +%F-%R`.log 2>&1
```